# How do I check if a Nintendo Switch game card supports multiple languages?

Tags: region-lock, nintendo-switch

According to the FAQ on Nintendo website, the Nintendo Switch console and its games are not region locked.

However, will a game card bought in a region contain languages of other regions? For example, should I buy a game while in Japan, will it be only in Japanese or in other languages too?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check the Nintendo eShop, by searching for the game title. In the details (no. players etc.), it should say supported languages - this should work since most if not all physical releases should be on eShop

Comment: This seems to be the answer I was looking for and didn't think of myself: I just went to check https://www.nintendo.it/Giochi/Nintendo-Switch/Super-Smash-Bros-Ultimate-1395713.html#gameDetails for example, and it lists Italian among the available languages.

Answer (score 2):

It depends.

If the game supports any other language than Japanese, you may play it in that language. It is not given that a game or a software will support languages of other regions, though. For example if you buy a game from Japan, you can't be sure it supports English. You should ask the vendor or read from the box what languages the game supports.

Your Nintendo Switch system tries to launch the game in your system's default language.

Source: https://en-americas-support.nintendo.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/22354/~/can-i-play-my-game-in-another-language%3F

Comment: Thanks for your answer, what I am not sure is: are languages supported always the same given a game, or can different cards of the same game, from different regions, support different languages?

Comment: Some games like Smash Bros is the same for all regions, and it's just the paper label on the cover being different. Changes like which default colour R.O.B. has (Famicom or NES colours) as well as if the name is "Duck Hunt" or "Duck Hunt Duo" is determined by the region chosen on the system. So it shouldn't matter where you buy that game from. -- However, some other games might have different versions sold in different regions, so be wary of that. -- Plus of course, not all games are available in all languages, but that one was obvious.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, actually you can download language packs for free on almost any game if the main game doesn't have multiple languages on settings. Most popular games have multiple language built-in especially the [Nintendo exclusives](https://allaboutgames.net/nintendo-switch/must-have-nintendo-switch-exclusives/).